# Open GZIP with classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, gzip

Is there any way or code sample to open GZIP stream with classic asp?

Answer (score 1):

This [COM object](http://www.xstandard.com/en/documentation/xzip/) will do the job.

http://www.xstandard.com/en/documentation/xzip/